# Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1

Tags: android, database, firebase

There was no error resolving com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1   and com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding google() repo in top level gradle file :

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
// ...
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services 
plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
   // ...
   repositories {
   // ...
   google() // Google's Maven repository
 } 
}
```

Comment: I already had added Google's Maven repository, but didn't use the latest version of  Google play services. Thanks!

Comment: @BarathR Yes, that was the issue here. I don't know why there is not a clear error message for this. And why not Android Studio try to update version in gradle file after installing the latest version.

Comment: version mentioned in answer. you may accept it.